# Error: finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem with Android Studio. When I add in my project the AndroidNetworking and modify the Manifest.xml, It gives me this error

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/androidnetworking/AndroidNetworking;
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

This is the code of the Android Manifest(I added tag `<uses-sdk/>`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="damasoft.mmchat">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" tools:overrideLibrary="com.androidnetworking"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <provider
        android:name="com.ianhanniballake.localstorage.LocalStorageProvider"
        android:authorities="com.ianhanniballake.localstorage.documents"
        android:enabled="@bool/use_provider"
        android:exported="true"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.action.DOCUMENTS_PROVIDER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </provider>
    <activity
        android:name="com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.FileChooserActivity"
        android:enabled="@bool/use_activity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/choose_file" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Page1" android:label="ManuPost"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".FileChooserActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "damasoft.mmchat"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:0.0.1'
}
```

I have tried to resolve this problem in the build.gradle, but without success

Comment: post your complete error log

Comment: do you use google api s ? eg: google maps?

Comment: clean & rebuild your project. For clean (project -> clean). and then run

Comment: I use APIs 23 in my project

Comment: It doesn't gives me another error

Comment: I've tried to clean & rebuild my project, but nothing

Comment: post your buld.gradle of app

Comment: don't use `<uses-sdk>` in your manifest as it is automatically overridden by build.gradle. So add minSDK n all that stuff in build.gradle(app level)  and then clean, rebuild and run project

Comment: But if I cancel <uses-sdk> It gives me another error

Comment: what's inside your `libs` folder? do you've `AndroidNetworking` jar file there?

Comment: No, I haven't this library

Comment: this error occurs when you've included the same library more than once, so are you sure you've not done that?

Comment: set `minifyEnabled` to `true` in the `build.gradle` file for debug mode, it should build then.

Comment: call `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'`  and   `multiDexEnabled true` then `Clean-Rebuild`

Comment: Every once in a while when i run out of resources (either RAM or CPU) i get this error.Are you building with enough available resources ? It sounds silly tho few times already i freed some resource and the next build was alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make multiDexEnabled true in your gradle file like

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.am.android"
    minSdkVersion 13
    targetSdkVersion 23
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

and compile

```
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

in your Mainactivity

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/androidnetworking/AndroidNetworking.class

Comment: where you are getting this ??

Comment: This is the new error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/androidnetworking/AndroidNetworking.class

Comment: try compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' after that clean and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Delete your Build folder then File>Invalidate Cache & Restart> then again build and Run .